# IntelliJ plugin or other software to generate Java code maps

Tags: java, programming, maps, productivity

**I'm looking for a program or a plugin to generate maps from Java source.**

Something that can be used either to improve my thinking process or use for documentation and presentation. Is there such a thing?

For other languages I see things like this quite often:
[image]

I'm looking for something to do that with Java. I know about BlueJ (at least I think it does this) but BlueJ is an entire seperate IDE and I just want something to supplement IntelliJ Idea.

If anyone knows where I could find such productivity software, please mention it. Thanks!